# Spring Boot Rest controller: adding text in the return type

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, datatable, restful-architecture

I have a SpringBoot app. with a RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/aggreg")
public class AggregRestController  {

@GetMapping("/list")
    public List<AggregCalcTrainsXCompany> aggregList  ()
            throws IOException, URISyntaxException, DataAccessException, SQLException {

        return aggregService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Since I want to use this controller in a DataTable ajax call, I would need to add this piece of code in the beginning:

```
{
  "data":
```

and `}` at the end to make it work, but I don't know if this is possible

Comment: Use a `Map<String, List<...>>` as return type, and in your method instantiate a `HashMap`, associate aggregService.findAll() to the "data" key. Then return the map.

Comment: @MarcTarin, please convert to answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you simply need to return a `Map` instead of a `List<AggregCalcTrainsXCompany>`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/aggreg")
public class AggregRestController  {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Map<String, List<AggregCalcTrainsXCompany>> aggregList  ()
            throws IOException, URISyntaxException, DataAccessException, SQLException {
        Map<String, List<AggregCalcTrainsXCompany>> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("data", aggregService.findAll());

        return m;
    }
}
```

The map will be serialized as

```
{
   "data" : <here the result from your aggregtation> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Wrap your List into class with `data` field and return it:

   ```
   class Result {
       List<AggregCalcTrainsXCompany> data;
   }
   ```
2. (as comment suggested) Return `Map<String, List<AggregCalcTrainsXCompany>>`